# Margin button in v-card does not take effect

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have this:

```
<v-card height="200">          
   <v-card-actions class="mb-0">
      <v-btn flat color="orange">Share</v-btn>
      <v-btn flat color="orange">Explore</v-btn>
   </v-card-actions>
</v-card>
```

The effect is this:

[image]

As you can see from the code, I want the button to have margin set to 0, but they still appear as if I set margin top to zero. How to fix this?

[**Codpen**](https://codepen.io/begueradj-the-sasster/pen/gEvbvq?editors=1010)

Answer (score 2):

It's because not the `margin` which affect your layout but it was `padding` you can use: `pl-0 pr-0 pb-0 pt-0` to set all `padding` to 0 or add custom class which declare `padding: 0` on `<v-card-actions>`: `.v-card__actions{padding:0}`

[Fork](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wOyaVe?editors=1010)

Answer (score 2):

Try this which removes padding in "all" directions:

```
<v-card-actions class="pa-0" >
```

When you inspect your element if the space around the element is green it means that it is a padding and orange means it is a margin. In your case it was a padding that would cause the issue. 
You can read more about **spacing helpers** [here.](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/spacing)